# How to call MVC controller action method from an android application based on java?

Tags: java, c#, android, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I developed a MVC application and also published, I use AJAX to call my controller methods

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ "async": false });
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            traditional: true,
            url: "/ETPWebsite/GetMETPrograms",
            data: {
                "TopicId": TopicId,
                "FreePrograms": FreePrograms,
                "PaidPrograms": PaidPrograms
            },
            success: function (result) {
                // Some Code
            },
            error: function (result) {
                // Some Code
            }
        });
```

in the above code, I gave /{Controller Name}/{Action Name} in the AJAX url section.
These controller methods are very significant and calls my business logic, rewriting them in java is not what I prefer.
I intended to develop an android app for the same application. Now i have started using android studio to develop. Instead of writing the same business logic and data retrievals in java. I was wondering if android architecture would support something similar to AJAX to call my controller methods.
Asynchronous is not actually necessary but i would like to call my controller methods which is published by giving a url "www.tpms.co.in/{Controller Name}/{Action Name}".

**Summarized:** 
Technically I would like to call my c# MVC controller methods from java.

Please help and suggest some alternatives if the question is lame and not feasible..!! ;-P

Comment: You can make a request to your website, what's the problem?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin How do i do that from an android app..?

Comment: Why don;t you just google that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an HTTP request with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: How is this question upvoted? It isn't even related to `c#` or any of the `.NET` frameworks